# Access ${..} in jsp tags

Tags: java, magnolia

I'm using magnolia and I have this variable:

`${def.parameters.subTemplate}`

I want to set the variable `subPath`, I'm doing the following below

```
<% String subPath= ${def.parameters.subTemplate};  %>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<c:set var="subPath" value="${def.perameters.subTemplate" />
```

and then

```
${subPath}
```